# Can not send data to USB Device connected to Android Device Host after sleep

Tags: android, printing, usb

I have the following setup:

Tablet: **Panasonic FZ-A2**

Connected on regular USB 2.0 port: **Thermal Printer**

The tablet also has an additional USB Type C connector.

When the printer is connected, printing works, we can send data to the printer and receive data from it.

**After the power button on the device is pressed the screen turns off and when it is pressed again the device wakes but sending data to the printer does not work any more**.

The only ways to make the printer working again is to unplug/replug the USB cable or power cable or restart the tablet.

The listing of the devices, opening UsbDeviceConnection, claiming interface and write operation are done each time separately and there is no re-use.

I am sure that we are using the correct endpoints with correct direction of data.

Also, when USB debugging is enabled and a cable connected on the other USB Type C port connected on the tablet, the problem does not manifest probably because the ADB debugging connection on the USB C port keeps wake the regular USB port where the printer is connected as a side effect.

Also, when the tablet is running on battery, the problem does not manifest at all.

**Edit 1:**

After implementing a background service that acquires partial wake lock from the Power Manager the issue is no longer reproducible.

This prevents the device to go to sleep mode even when the power button is pressed.

Still the underlying problem is still present.
If the app is killed, the problem can still be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to find a real solution to this problem but a workaround by aquiring partial wake lock and never releasing it.
This prevents the USB host going to sleep mode.
Note that the wake lock needed to be aquired in a background service and did not work properly if done on Application.create().

```
public class WakeLockService extends Service {

  public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1337;

  private final transient Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WakeLockService.class);

  private void start(int paramInt) {
    logger.info("Wake lock service starting");

    // acquire wake lock
    WakeLocker.acquire(this);

    NotificationCompat.Builder localBuilder;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    localBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    localBuilder.setContentTitle("Wake lock");
    localBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    localBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_power_settings_new_gray_48dp);
    localBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    localBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, localBuilder.build());
  }

  private void stop() {
    WakeLocker.release();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wake lock stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopForeground(true);
  }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent paramIntent) {
    return null;
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    stop();
  }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent paramIntent, int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
    start(0);
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }
}
```

The service is started on App.onCreate():

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // start wake lock
    startService(new Intent(this, WakeLockService.class));
}
```